# Can't make content sit right below fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

I'm trying to make my `content-full` sit right below my navbar, but using `padding` doesn't produce the result that I want.

Tried applying `margin-top` to `content-full` but it adds margin to my navbar.

Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/make96/pen/KoROxZ) and here is a screenshot
[image] of exactly what I want to achieve.

Jade:

```
nav
 .box
  #nav-icon1
   span
   span
   span
   span
 ul
  li
   a(href="#") Despre
  li
   a(href="#") FAQ
  li
   a(href="#") Numere
  li
   a(href="#") Colectiv
.content-full
 .content
  h1 test
```

SASS:

```
nav
 width: 100%
 position: fixed
 ul
  text-align: center
  background: #ffffff
  width: 68vw
  margin: 0 auto
  li
   display: inline-block
   width: 15vw
   a
    color: #a3a3a3
    display: block
    padding: 3vh 6vw
    text-decoration: none
.content-full
 padding: 10vh 0 0 0
 background: #a3a3a3
 .content
  width: 68vw
  min-height: 80vh
  background: blue
  margin: 0 auto
```

Comment: The only problem I see is that you use paddings in vh, which causes the result to depend on the height of the window. Use paddings in em instead (because that is how the height of the nav bar is calculated).

Answer (score 0):

The margin you're seeing is not from the bar, it's from the content.
Basically, you have that *position: fixed* that is keeping the nav section on top and "fixed".

If you remove/lower the padding from the content, they will stick together.

You have a few possibilities you can try:

1. make the padding a little lower so the content will "stick"
2. remove the position fixed.
3. rework the nav from *position: fixed* to *position: absolute* with *top:0* and remove the padding (although this one is pretty tricky and unreliable on the long run).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe you are looking for: [working link](https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/GxGKrE)

```
nav
  width: 100%
  position: fixed
  min-height: 13vh
  ul
    text-align: center
    background: #ffffff
    width: 68vw
    min-height: 13vh
    margin: 0 auto
    li
      display: inline-block
      width: 15vw
      min-height: 13vh
      a
        color: #a3a3a3
        display: block
        padding: 3vh 6vw
        text-decoration: none
.content-full
  padding: 13vh 0 0 0
  background: #a3a3a3
  .content
    width: 68vw
    min-height: 87vh
    background: blue
    margin: 0 auto
```

This is responsive also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that tech but I got the result by changing the UL width to 100%, taking the padding off .content-full and putting it on .content with a padding of 3em. But this seem to be a quick fix and you may run into problems down the road. Best of luck!